# Do combatants have to assign dice from their pool to be able to move in combat?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-the-apocalypse-2nd-edition

**How exactly does combat movement work in Werewolf: The Apocalypse** (preferably the game's 2nd edition)?

(Do combatants have to allocate at least one dice from their combat pool - itself being possibly significantly lowered by having to switch to a weaker pool based on their movement, Dex+Athletics? - if they want to move in a given round?)

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I and the group that I play White Wolf games with do play fast and loose with the rules.)

A certain amount of movement happens in combat - just take a look at any fencing, boxing or MMA fight.

So the only time I’d tell a player to do that [i.e. split a die pool] in *Werewolf* would be if the movement was covering a large distance (like a 10m sprint) or it was complicated (like acrobatics - say back flips), and the actor doesn’t have an ability that would allow for an extra action - like spending a rage point or the *Vampire* ability celerity.

World of Darkness, Core Rulebook, page 164:

> [Combat] Movement: Your character's Speed trait indicates how many yards he can travel in a single turn by walking or jogging. He can travel that many yards and still perform an action, all in the same turn. He can move and perform an action, or perform an action and then move. He cannot, however, move, perform an action and then move again all in the same turn. If he moves more quickly, he can travel up to twice his Speed trait in a turn by running. Doing so is considered a full action and no other feats can usually be performed while running. A special Merit or supernatural power is required to accomplish such combined tasks, or your character charges (see below).

Werewolf: The Apocalypse (revised), page 196

> Movement in combat: No roll is required to move, but movement takes a full action. In some situations, such as crossing treacherous ground or running amid a hail of bullets, the Storyteller may call for an Athletics roll to move or simply rule that movement at full distance is impossible.

Hence: complicated/long distance movement and an attack (another complicated action), split your dice pool between the attack and the complex movement. Otherwise, move then attack.

And finally: WtA, page 22

> …the rules in this book are useful only as a means to provide a framework for the story. If the rules conflict with the story, the story wins every time.

If splitting a dice pool helps your game and everyone to have fun, do it. If it doesn’t, don’t do it and do your own thing. It’s a rule in the game.

It’s worth keeping in mind garou can charge opponents, use special attacks and moves from their martial art kailindo which can allow them to combine movement towards, or away from, an opponent and attack in one action.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't have the 2nd edition book handy, but here's the rule from the 20th Anniversary edition:

> Moving: A character who wants to move more than a yard or two from where she currently stands must take an action to do so. This doesn’t normally require a roll, although treacherous or difficult circumstances (like trying to run on ice or through a firefight) might demand a Dexterity + Athletics roll at the Storyteller’s discretion. For different movement rates, see the nearby sidebar.
>   (page 269)

The walk speed for humans is 7 yards, and jog is 12 + dexterity.  1.5x for hispo, 2x for lupus.

Personally, I usually let them move their jog speed in exchange for dropping a single die off their combat pool, rather than the full split-pool rules unless they're going faster or doing something weird.